# convert an integer to a minimally-padded vector of bits (probably using BitVec)

Tags: rust, bit, bitvector

cross posting from https://github.com/bitvecto-rs/bitvec/issues/163

I'm trying to create compact binary representations of integers, with minimal padding. I'm currently reaching for [BitVec](https://github.com/bitvecto-rs/bitvec), but that's not necessarily the best solution. I'm actually putting together a simple arithmetic encoding scheme for lossy encoding of floats and integers, based on [this reference](https://libdccl.org/codecs.html). For that I need to do the following-

- truncate and scale input values to an unsigned integer value (this part isn't a problem)
- generate the most compact possible binary representation of that integer
- concatenate the bits with other encoded numbers

for a more concrete example, say i have the input value `100106`, then I can convert that to a binary string using `format`

```rust
println!("{:b}", 100106_usize);
// "011000011100001010"
```

if I naively convert the `usize` directly to a `BitVec`, then the value is padded

```rust
let bit_vec = BitVec::from_element(100106_usize);
println!("{:b}", bit_vec);
// "[0101000011100001100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000]"
```

i was playing around with bitwise operators and pushing bits into a `Vec<bool>`. That seems like it would work, but also like i was reinventing the wheel. I suspect i'm missing something obvious.

To be clear the binary representation needs *some* padding, but of variable width, since i need a fixed number of bits that can represent the largest possible value in a given range.
For example, if i wanted to represent values in the range (-10000..10000), then i can represent this by mapping to (0..20000), and the number of bits i need to store the largest possible value is `ceil(log2(20000)) == 18`. So to 'encode' into this representation i need to add 10000, and then encode as exactly 18 bits (i'm taking this example straight from the reference at https://libdccl.org/codecs.html)

Answer (score 0):

answer provided on the [github issue](https://github.com/bitvecto-rs/bitvec/issues/163):

```rust
use bitvec::prelude::*;

let num = 100_106usize;
let raw = num.view_bits::<Lsb0>();
let bits = raw.iter_ones().last().unwrap_or(bitvec::mem::bits_of::<usize>() - 1);
let bv = raw[..= bits].to_bitvec();
```